# Nexus-5 pulse notification LED wont work after lollipop OTA update

Tags: nexus-5, ota-update, 5.0-lollipop, notification-led

I got OTA update for my nexus 5 and one thing I noticed is my pulse notification light won't work after the update..no matter its a call or a watsapp message. Then I tried installing light flow it worked properly..but I don't want to use any third party apps. And my pulse notification is enabled at settings FYI. Is it a bug on lollipop? Any solution?

Comment: I just tried, it doesn't work on my phone either. Probably a bug.  
The light did't work properly on KitKat either ( for missed calls ) though.

Comment: I noticed it blinks for certain apps like google messenger and any.do. but still not like it worked with kitkat. I heard in nexus 6 it has rgb led but useless. Hope next update resolves this.